# Broken Rear mech inner plate

Tags: shimano, derailleur

My chain got caught in the guide plate and broke the encircled part of the rear mech (See photo) I'm using Shimano GRX 810 Rear derailleur. There are no observable misalignment. Question, is it safe to still use this Rear mech? I already ordered another one and I plan to use this while waiting

Comment: What photo?  I don't see one.

Comment: With or without photo, anyway I'd be very cautious and refrain from using a damaged RD. There could be risk of damaging the rear wheel as well or in the worst of cases having the RD pushed into the spokes and risking an accident.

Comment: Could you please try adding the photo again?  Use [edit] and the insert-image button is over the text area.

Comment: Had you considered asking your bike store if you could order just the broken part instead of a whole rear derailleur? The parts diagram, which contains a breakdown of the RD and all the part numbers, is here: https://si.shimano.com/#/en/iEV/RD-RX810